# Как логическое ударение может определяться интонацией, если

Tags: пунктуация, орфоэпия

Как логическое ударение может определяться интонацией, если в разных ситуациях можно произносить одно и тоже предложение абсолютно одинаково, но ударение не поменяется?

— Моих родителей вызывают из-за той драки?
— Твоих родителей просят прийти в школу из-за множества плохих отметок в школе. (ударение на причинный оборот, поэтому он не обособляется)

— Вы хотели меня видеть? Зачем вы меня вызвали?
— Твоих родителей просят прийти в школу, из-за множества плохих отметок в школе.(ударение не на причинный оборот)
Учитель может произнести эти предложения абсолютно одинаково. В обоих случаях перед причинным оборотом учитель может не делать паузу, но ударение то от этого не поменяется.

— Кто уезжает?
— Я уезжаю.

— Почему ты собираешься?
— Я уезжаю.

Представьте, что человек пародирует голосовой переводчик произнося эти предложения. От этого изменится ударение или смысл предложения? Нет! Ни ударение, ни смысл!

Изменение ударения зачастую сопровождает изменение интонации, но — не обязательно! Интонация обуславливается ударением, которое, в свою очередь, определяется центральными для смысла словами или сочетаниями, произносимыми в конкретной ситуации.

Если разобраться в этом вопросе, то семь страниц жалкой, мутной писанины Розенталя про деепричастные обороты можно заменить одним предложением: «Всегда обособляются, но только не под ударением.»

Возьмем предложение: «Он шел по улице прихрамывая.»

Каждый раз, выходя утром на улицу, я вижу человека, который совершает пробежку, но на этот раз он идет и прихрамывает. Вспоминая этот случай, я скажу: «Он шел по улице, прихрамывая». Ударение на «шел». Важно то, что он шел, а не бежал.

Я не видел своего друга Никиту пару дней. Я вижу, как он идет по улице и прихрамывает. Прихрамывание примечательно для меня, так как заставляет задуматься о том, что с ним случилось. Вспоминая это, я скажу: «Он шел по улице прихрамывая.» Ударение на «прихрамывая». Важно то, что он идет прихрамывая.

Comment: Я полагаю, что автор описывает нам свое восприятие речи, и не могу заранее исключать, что там есть какие-то интересные наблюдения. Но мы не можем говорить на разных языках. Я предлагаю ему сделать то же самое, но в  общепринятой терминологии. Думаю, что нужно ответственно подходить к использованию каждого слова, когда речь идет о теоретических аспектах  языка.

Comment: Я не могу считать его формализацию слабой? Какая там у него была биография? Несмотря на то, что сестра била его мокрым носком, он смог выучится на лингвиста и пилить гос.бабки написанием справочников?

Comment: Еще раз что ли пояснить, вроде бы уже говорила. Филологи вам не нравятся? Вы не понимаете, что Правила не Розенталь написал, что это результат 300-летнего развития русского языка, необходимый этап в освоении нашей культуры. Это та площадка, с которой продолжится развитие, а вы нас призываете  двигаться к хаосу, в вашу неорганизованную материю, вот уж действительно мутную. Розенталь же написанные в 1956 году тезисы правил воплотил в жизнь, раскрыл их подробное содержание, вот за это мы ему багодарны. Мы, но не вы. Вам не кажется, что вы просто не умеете быть благодарным, а это грустно..

Comment: Формализация — это описание, а не создание. Я ни к чему никого не призывал.

Comment: Может я и перебарщиваю иногда с резкими оценками, но в любом случае формализация, максимум, средняя. Проблема скорее в отсутствии последующих попыток как-то более удачно все формализовать. Я никогда и не отрицал, что справочник Розенталя лучший из имеющихся.

Comment: Давайте вести обсуждение менее эмоционально.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122500/discussion-on-question-by-jim-korbett-----).

Comment: Непонятно, почему вы читаете Розенталя, ища что-то об ударении и интонации. Есть работы, специально посвященные этим темам и написанные специалистами в соответствующих областях.

Answer (score 3):

**Ваша формулировка вопроса:** Как **логическое** ударение может определяться **интонацией,** если в разных ситуациях можно произносить одно и тоже предложение абсолютно **одинаково,** но ударение **не поменяется**?

Вопрос звучит не очень понятно.

Я не даю вам ответа на него, так как мы с вами достаточно говорили на эту тему. Но я предлагаю вам **самим ответить на вопрос**, используя **точные** определения и характеристики всех терминов.

Только в этом случае наши рассуждения **не напоминают наши фантазии.**  Я думаю, что такой подход  важен для любых областей  науки, в том числе для лингвистики (а именно на языкознание ориентирован наш форум).

Таким образом, **в качестве вступления** я предлагаю вам объяснить терминологию, которую вы **собираетесь  использовать** в ответе (а также уже использовали в вопросе).

1. Что вы  понимаете **под одинаковым произношением?**
2. Что вы знаете **об ударении и его видах** (можно привести сравнительный анализ из разных языков)?

В обоих случаях я имею в виду:

1. **Точные фонетические** (звуковые) **характеристики** устной речи: тон, сила звука, тембровая окраска речи, длительность пауз и т.д.
2. Как они используются **в семантических целях** (какова их знаковая нагрузка)?  (В принципе мы можем считать ударение таким же фонетическим знаком, как и сам звук.)

**Приложение**

Для вашей успешной работы вы можете использовать следующие **термины:**

**Интона́ция** (лат. intonō «громко произношу») — совокупность **просодических** характеристик предложения: тона (мелодики речи), громкости, темпа речи и её отдельных отрезков, ритмики, особенностей фонации.
**Просо́дия** (др.-греч. προςῳδία «ударение», буквально «припевание»)

**Высота звука** — свойство звука, определяемое человеком на слух и зависящее в основном от частоты звука, то есть от числа колебаний среды (обычно воздуха) в секунду, которые воздействуют на барабанную перепонку человека.

**Тон в лингвистике** — использование высоты звука для смыслоразличения в рамках слов/морфем. Тон следует отличать от интонации, то есть изменения высоты тона на протяжении сравнительно большого речевого отрезка (высказывания или предложения).

**Музыкальное/тоническое ударение** выделяет слог не силой звука, а его высотой, которая определяется частотой колебания голосовых связок.  Интенсивность звука (сила звука) — это физическая величина, характеризующая мощность (энергетику) звука.

**Сила звука** зависит, как полагают, от амплитуды колеблющегося тела вообще, в данном случае – от амплитуды колебания голосовых связок.

**Темп речи** — скорость произнесения элементов речи (звуков, слогов, слов). Относится к **просодическим** элементам, является одним из компонентов интонации. Следует заметить, что абсолютный темп речи зависит от индивидуальных черт говорящего.

**Тембр речи** – это индивидуальная окраска, совокупность дополнительных колебаний или обертонов, которые возникают наряду с основной частотой.

**Пауза** – это временная остановка звучания, разрывающая поток речи, вызываемая разными причинами и выполняющая **различные функции.**

**Логическое ударение** – это выделение голосом наиболее значимых слов в предложении. Логическое ударение является средством только устной речи, его нельзя обозначить на письме.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

**Интонация** – это сложная характеристика, поэтому для интонационного анализа удобно использовать **интонационные модели.**

Я пользуюсь моделью, в которую входит **три основные характеристики**: тоническое ударение, логическое ударение и паузы различной длительности.

Этого вполне достаточно для того, чтобы по интонационной модели  назвать **вид интонации** – перечислительная, разделительная, присоединительная, пояснительная, а затем определить **знак препинания.**

Comment: «Одинаково»... значит одинаково... во всех пяти, бл... , смыслах.  Одинаковый темп, одинаковый тон, одинаковый тембр, одинаковые паузы между словами и тд. Мы не говорили с вами на эту тему. Когда разговор переходит на эту тему — все всегда умолкают. Филологи, привыкшие запоминать нормы в промышленных масштабах, выпадают за текстуры, когда нужно подумать своей головой. И что бы вы могли сказать на это?! Приводимые мною аргументы — безусловное доказательство. Обособление оборотов объясняется не бредовыми интонационными теориями, а ударением, которое не зависит от характера произношения.

Comment: «Кто уезжает?» — «Я уезжаю». «Почему ты собираешься?» — «Я уезжаю». Я вот об этой штуковине. От нее зависит обособление оборотов.  Можете назвать это хоть «жопное» ударение.

Comment: Ответа нет, необоснованная просьба уточнить слово «одинаково». Ответ не был полезен — минус.

Comment: Да не волнуйтесь вы так, никто вас здесь не обижает. Я к вам сначала вообще отнеслась к симпатией, вы же помните, наверное. Я вам предложила вариант, как исправить ситуацию. Мы не можем что-то обсуждать, если  будем говорить о разных вещах, только время будем терять. И что особенного в ваших предложениях? Повышение тона при вопросе, понижение тона при ответе, логическим ударением выделено нужное слово.  Логическое ударение здесь - это смещение тонического ударения с конца фразы на другое слово. А с лексикой вам бы быть поаккуратнее, пока ею не заинтересовался строгий модератор.

Comment: @JimKorbett  Ваши комментарии, вопросы и ответы всё больше наводят на мысль, что нас (меня) хотят запутать. Ударения нет – нет интонации ("Одинаковый темп, одинаковый тон, одинаковый тембр, одинаковые паузы между словами и тд".) Появляется ударение – появляется интонация ("**Я** уезжаю. Я **уезжаю**.)  Обособление зависит от ударения – элемента интонации. Вы сами ответили на все свои вопросы.

Comment: Нет! Предложения не существуют в вакууме. Именно ситуация, в которой произносится предложения, создает ударение. Ударение появляется, когда предложение произносится в реальном мире, а уж интонация является производным от него. «Я уезжаю» и «Я уезжаю» — я могу произнести их абсолютно одинаково в разных ситуациях и смысл все равно будет, ударение все равно будет и я все равно буду понят.

Comment: Вы постоянно противоречите самому себе. Желаю удачи в дальнейшем!

Comment: Дабы определять ударение нужно изменять контексты, а не менять характер произношения. Наверное, у меня какой-то магический дар, так как я определяю ударение совершенно не задумываясь об интонации.

Comment: @Jim Korbett "Логическое ударение" - терминологическая условность. Это один из _необязательных_ элементов интонации. Но в  отдельных случаях интонационное выделение слов модифицирует _смысл_. В вашем недавнем примере (**Я уезжаю**) один из интонационных вариантов отвечает на вопрос "_**кто** из нас уедет?_", а другой - на вопрос "_какие у тебя планы?_" Эти два вопроса возникают в разных контекстах, которым соответствует и _разная интонация_ прочтения.

Comment: Я согласен, что интонация иногда вносит изменения в смысл. В остальном я не понял, что вы хотели сказать.

Comment: @Jim Korbett, из всей вашей писанины(уж простите за резкость, иначе это не назовешь), можно сделать один вывод: правильно так, потому что я так считаю. Ни одного научного аргумента, ни одного анализа, никаких выводов.

Comment: @Серж, ударение сохраняется разным при одинаковом произношении. Какие еще нужны доказательства?

Comment: @Jim Korbett, похоже, вы запутались в своих суждениях. Сперва вы пишете, что ударение не меняется, а потом пишете, что сохраняется разным.

Comment: Кстати, выражение  "сохраняется разным" речевая ошибка.

Comment: В каждом отдельном предложении не меняется. Вы берете два одинаковых предложения, но с разными ударениями, произносите их одинаково в соответствующих ситуациях, но в каждом отдельном предложении ударение сохраняется. Если бы ударение определялось характером произношения, то и менялось бы ударение.

Comment: Не речевая ошибка, а оговорка.

Comment: Предложения: «Я — уезжаю» и «Я уезжаю» — произносятся с разными целями: сообщить автора действия и сообщить само действие. Контекст формирует цель, а цель — ударение, а ударение — интонацию.

Comment: Кстати, в предложении: «Кстати, выражение «сохраняется разным» речевая ошибка» — пунктуационная ошибка — пропущенное тире.

Comment: Эта штуковина, про ударение, не определяемое характером произношения, — крайне важна, так как если ударение определяется интонацией, то любой оборот можно обособлять по желанию, а потом сказать, что вот тут такая вот особая интонация.

Answer (score 1):

Я разберу в качестве образца только одно предложения: ***Твоих родителей просят прийти в школу из-за множества плохих отметок.***

**1. Решение по Розенталю**

Оборот имеет значение причины, что определяется по предлогу ИЗ-ЗА. По правилам Розенталя обстоятельственные обороты обособляются факультативно, причем с помощью обособления подчеркивается причинное значение оборота (делается его актуализация). Чаще обособляются обороты с производными предлогами как аналоги придаточных предложений (в связи с множеством плохих отметок в школе), но при этом также учитывается позиция оборота и его распространенность.

Постановка запятой в заданном предложении **выглядит как ошибка,** запятую могут посчитать лишней. Это определяется  структурой предложения, а именно постпозицией оборота. Если нужно **выделить это сообщение**, то следует использовать другую конструкцию, например:

***Твоих родителей просят прийти в школу, так как у тебя множество плохих отметок.***

***Твоих родителей просят прийти в школу – у тебя множество плохих отметок.***

**2. Дополнительный интонационный анализ**

**Почему запятая будет считаться лишней**

При ответах на тему лишних запятых желательно использовать именно этот метод.

***Твоих родителей просят прийти в шкОлу // из-за множества плохих отмЕток.***

Это типичная интонационная структура простого предложения: две фразы, разделенные произносительной паузой по принципу «тема – причина как сообщение по теме». Тоническое ударение падает на конец каждой фразы, но в конце предложения более сильная ударная позиция, соответственно, дополнительное силовое логическое выделение там **выглядит неестественно** (в нем нет необходимости).  При прочтении предложения будет выбран именно этот вариант (без обособления),  поэтому запятую посчитают ошибочной, лишней.

**Другие варианты**

***Твоих родителей просят прийти в шкОлу, // так как у тебя множество плохих отмЕток.***

Пауза здесь подчеркнутая, грамматическая, она обозначается запятой. Полноценное тоническое ударение в конце каждой фразы.

***Твоих родителей просят прийти в шкОлу – // у тебя множество плохих отмЕток.***

Это присоединительный оборот, обозначенный подчеркнутой паузой (более сильный знак, чем запятая). В данном случае причина не подчеркивается, а называется. Такая конструкция выглядит естественно и хорошо узнается как на письме, так и в устной речи. Ударение аналогичное.

Таким образом, мы видим, что во всех вариантах **нет силового логического выделения,** интонация спокойная. Но при постановке запятой четко обозначается как пауза, так и тоническое ударение в конце первой части.

Спасибо за внимание, обсуждать тему с  автором вопроса я не планирую, за что прошу у него извинения.

**Дополнение (некоторые рассуждения по теме)**

Я уже давно работаю на форуме и хотела бы поделиться с вами мнением по некоторым вопросам.  Вы произвели на меня сначала хорошее впечатление и даже помогли в решении некоторых проблем. Возможно, у вас действительно неплохое чувство языка, но тогда нужно пользоваться этим преимуществом (только умело пользоваться) и развивать в себе сильные стороны.

В то же время нежелательно рассуждать о теории или правилах письма, если вы не знаете их **на очень хорошем уровне.** Но даже в этом случае нужно избегать **любых резких суждений и оценок** – они будут восприняты крайне отрицательно. Разумная дипломатия, вежливость и корректное поведение – это то, что ценится в любом обществе.

**1. Какова аудитория форума?**

Прежде всего, это **люди с практическими интересами**, которые хотят узнать не только как пишется, но и почему так пишется Им нужны правила, на которые они могут сослаться, поэтому желательно давать ссылки при ответах. Вряд ли им интересны чьи-то мнения, в какой-то мере  (на слово») они могут доверять только ответам Грамоты.ру, на которые возможны ссылки.

Ко второй группе можно отнести тех, кому **интересен сам русский язык** (в эту группу входят постоянные участники). Кто-то неплохо разбирается в теории, другие имеют практический опыт  или хорошее чувство языка. Они отвечают на вопросы, обмениваются мнениями, но их мировоззрение в этой области вполне сложившееся. Они могут что-то уточнить для себя, но ничего принципиального менять **не собираются.** И они тоже работают **в рамках правил.**

Очевидно, что ни тем, ни другим никакие **революционные инновации** не нужны, и уж тем более исходящие от малоизвестных лиц.

**2. О справочнике Розенталя**

Розенталя можно любить или не любить, но желательно понимать, что на сегодняшний день это справочник, приравненный **к официальным правилам.** Соответственно, даже ПАС под редакцией Лопатина в каждой статье дает ссылку на  соответствующую тему у Розенталя (**для  сравнения материала**), например: **Этот параграф у Розенталя: § 5 п. 1**

Таким образом, это самый **авторитетный источник**, в том числе на форуме,  и любые нападки на него будут восприниматься крайне негативно.

**3. Об интонационном анализе**

Как известно, правила пунктуации  основаны на трех принципах – семантическом, грамматическом и интонационном. Интонация считается главным средством связи в бессоюзном сложном предложении. Также об интонации неоднократно упоминает и Розенталь,  на грамматический принцип в этих правилах является основным.

Интонационный анализ – это **новый метод,** еще мало освоенный, но очень эффективный. В то же время он **не отрицает** правил Розенталя, а **дополняет их** в том случае, когда это необходимо (часто при наличии вариантов при грамматическом решении).

Поэтому при использовании интонационного анализа указание **на официальные справочники** (ПАС и Розенталь) также является необходимым.

Comment: _**Sharon**: Розенталя можно любить или не любить, но желательно понимать, что на сегодняшний день это справочник, приравненный к официальным правилам. Соответственно, даже **ПАС под редакцией Лопатина постоянно ссылается на него в каждой своей теме.**_   === Ну Вы даёте!!! ПАС ссылается на Розенталя? 

Comment: slava1947, а вы можете хотя бы что-то сказать в мой адрес ДОБРОЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНО И БЕЗ ИРОНИИ. Вы так просто не умеете, да? Например, подошел бы такой вариант: «Мне кажется, что у Вас эта мысль изложена не совсем точно и корректно». Что касается мысли, то она изложена с надеждой на понимающую аудиторию, но я ее исправлю по возможности.

Comment: _**Sharon:** slava1947, а вы можете хотя бы что-то сказать в мой адрес ДОБРОЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНО И БЕЗ ИРОНИИ. Вы так просто не умеете, да? Например, подошел бы такой вариант: «Мне кажется, что у Вас эта мысль изложена не совсем точно и корректно»._ === Гм… К сожалению, в данном случае вариант с "мысль изложена не совсем точно и корректно" вряд ли возможен. Некорректно и неточно не изложение Вами своей мысли… Сама мысль! 

Comment: Гениально! Просто  удовольствие  получаю, вас  читая. Судя по зачину, разговор на пару дней. А вы не могли бы сразу начать с вашей корректной мысли? Да и вообще, редко вы заходите на форум. Уж поучили бы нас  уму-разуму! А то только комментарии пишете  и все мне посвящаете, будто некому больше.